# How do I monitor connections to my Modbus Slave in android, using J2Mod?

Tags: java, android, server, monitoring, modbus

I am currently writing a Modbus TCP/IP Slave using the J2Mod V 3.0.  I have created the slave and have it listening on the correct port and can connect to it from my PC (using Simply Modbus).  What I cannot seem to figure out is how do I monitor the connections that my Slave is receiving?  How do I know when a Master writes to one of my registers?  Any help is appreciated. I am including how I setup the slave just in case that helps.

```
void createSlave() {
    try {
        String ip = Model.getInstance().plcSettings().getIPAddress(true);
        String[] ipStringArray = ip.split("\\.");
        byte[] addr = new byte[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < ipStringArray.length; i++) {
            addr[i] = Byte.parseByte(ipStringArray[i]);
        }

        slave = ModbusSlaveFactory.createTCPSlave(InetAddress.getByAddress(addr), port, 5, false, (Model.getInstance().plcSettings().getIdleTimeout() * 60));
        slave.addProcessImage(1, image);
        slave.open();
    } catch (NumberFormatException | ModbusException | UnknownHostException modException) {
        modException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually reached out and was responded to by Steve O'Hara.  It turns out with J2mod there is currently no way to monitor a connection.  Shout out to him for responding and being so cool about everything.